# Gerrit/git: rename java class to existing (remove middleman)

Tags: java, git, rename, gerrit

We use git, with Gerrit as a code review tool, and we have a model class (MyModelImpl) with associated interface (MyModel). We have realized that this setup is overkill, so we want to remove the interface. We also want to keep the MyModel classname in the code. So we want to remove "MyModel.java" and rename "MyModelImpl.java" to "MyModel.java", and change the contents so that everything compiles. And we want to keep the history of the file formerly known as "MyModelImpl.java" intact.

Is it possible to do this in a single commit?

We have tried of course, and what we see in Gerrit is that "MyModelImpl.java" has been removed, and "MyModel.java" has been thoroughly changed. And the history of "MyModelImpl.java" is lost.

We want to do it in a single commit because just removing "MyModel.java" would result in a commit that doesn't compile, and doing a commit with all usage of MyModel converted to MyModelImpl followed by a second commit with MyModelImpl renamed to MyModel would result in huge commits (mostly cancelling each other out) that would be a pain to code review.

Answer (score 0):

Your first approach was perfectly right - and the history should still intact for `MyModel.java`. However, you must not run `git log MyModel.java` but `git log --follow MyModel.java` instead. If you feel more comfortable with your second approach, you can "squash" commits (which makes multiple commits one commit) via an interactive rebase: `git rebase -i`. This should not be necessary in your case though. If you decide not to use `git rebase` you should still read the man page about it. It's an awesome command!

Comment: Yeah we ended up doing using the former way - one commit that didn't compile so we had to force it through Gerrit. I don't think squashing will help here - a squashed commit would be the same as if we did it all in one commit to start with. I agree that rebase is a brilliant command - use it all the time :)